# Kids show with alien grandparents looking like elves or goblins

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

Just rewatched Harry Potter 1 and  the bank gremlins triggered a memory flash of this show my sister used to watch in the 2000/10s (but it might be older). She used to watch a lot Disney channel and Nickelodeon but not in the UK or US so the broadcast was maybe delayed.

2 old aliens crash at a house and are integrated into the family as grandparents (or aunt and uncle ?) to prevent any suspicion from the neighbors. I don’t remember them having magic powers but they are always trying to help the kids.
I really have the memory of small “muppets” (again, kind of like the Harry Potter gringotts gremlins) or actors with heavy make up to look old. They are very small and I think the grandma has purple hairs. They might have cat or mouse attributes in the face.

I really hope they are not some kind of fairy, elf or that this memory flash was not invented : the internet didn’t have any answer with any of my “kid tv show with alien/etc grandparents”.

Comment: I know there was a British show called *My Parents Are Aliens* that had a similar premise, but the titular alien parents were live-action.

Comment: Also a British show called _Mike and Angelo_, but only one small elvish alien and he was live-action also.

Comment: And [_Aliens in the Family_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115090) has puppets/muppets, but they are big and the other plot points don't match